# php download file header echo

Tags: php, header, download

i got code like this

```
          [... page content]
          header("Content-type: application/x-download");
          header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);
          header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".urlLastSeg($buttons['Torrent file(Torcache)']));
          header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
          echo $filecontent ;
```

then browser prompts to save file but the file contains html of the page with binary data attached at the end instead of binary data alone.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the headers at the bottom? It is called *headers* because they are on top of the response.

It beats me that this should trigger a file download. I guess you missed to show some code. A working example would look like this (and nothing more(!)):

```
  <?php

  $filename = '...';
  header("Content-type: application/x-download");
  header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filename));
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $filename;
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  readfile($filename);
```

Comment: well, i want to display some page and then push the file to user. if the headers were at the begining, user would see blank white screen after clicking download link ?

Comment: You need to understand [http](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: after clicking download link it loads new page containing info 'download will start shortly', and then browser 'download prompt' should appear to user.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you need to set your headers before *any* other output.

Comment: are you sure? what about buffer operations?

Comment: If you are using a buffer then the headers get sent before everything else anyway.